# Counting the frequency of combinations of numbers (in excel using VBA)

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I want excel to count the `FREQUENCY` that certain number-letter combinations appear down a column in excel (using [vba](/questions/tagged/vba)). All my data goes down one column like this:

Column A (only 1,2,3,4,5,s,f appear)

> 1
>   2
>   s
>   4
>   3
>   s
>   4
>   2
>   f
>   2
>   s
>   2
>   s

I want to count the number of occasions combinations of (1-s, 2-s, 3-s, 4-s, 5-s) occur, strictly when the number occurs first (is in the higher row). I do not want to count occasions when the s comes before the number (e.g. s-2). I know how to count the number of individual letters/numbers using the countIf function.

I might later want to expand my analysis to look at the occasions that three letter-number combinations (e.g. 2-s-3, 2-s-5)

I am very much a VBA noob.

Comment: What would be the result of the above example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try inserting a new column to the right of Column A.  Use this formula `=A1&A2` and fill it down the column.  The values will look like this:

```
+----------+----------+
| Column A | Column B |
+----------+----------+
| 1        | 12       |
| 2        | 2s       |
| s        | s4       |
| 4        | 43       |
| 3        | 3s       |
| s        | s4       |
| 4        | 42       |
| 2        | 2f       |
| f        | f2       |
| 2        | 2s       |
| s        | s2       |
| 2        | 2s       |
| s        | s        |
+----------+----------+
```

Now you can count occurences like you were doing before! :D

---

Of course, you can expand to three character frequency analysis by making the formula `=A1&A2&A3`.

Comment: Thanks, I used this method in the end, since it was a very simple solution!

Answer (score 0):

Seems possible with COUNTIFS, with `1` to `5` inclusive in C1:G1 and in C2:

```
=COUNTIFS($A1:$A12,C1,$A2:$A13,"s")
```

copied across to suit.

Comment: Request asked for VBA

Comment: `If you feel that’s reason for -1, feel free` - nope. Else I would have downvoted. Comment is fine :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the VBA equivalent of this formula

`=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(A1:A12)),--(A2:A13="s"))`

which looks for number, followed by `s` in the row below (4 for your sample)

**code**

```
MsgBox Evaluate("SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(A1:A12)),--(A2:A13=""s""))")
```